# Cannot load fonts in Laravel 5.7 & Vue 2 project using Element UI & iView UI Toolkit

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.7, element-ui, iview-ui

I recently installed laravel v5.7 and vue 2. I then installed [Element UI](http://element.eleme.io)
and [iView UI Toolkit](https://www.iviewui.com/), everything works perfectly, but anything that uses icons in any iView UI component shows square blocks, but i want the result to look like the [documentation](https://www.iviewui.com/components/alert-en) where i the alert has an icon. I have searched and tried many solutions but none worked e.g)

> What I've done so far

1. Editting the .htaccess file according to this [article](https://github.com/fontello/fontello/wiki/How-to-setup-server-to-serve-fonts)
2. Installed [Laravel Cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)
3. Confirmed that the fonts exist in **"/fonts/vendor/iview/dist/styles"** after running **npm run watch**
4. Cleared my cache, history, everything.
   5) Checked that the css file is being referenced properly.
   6) Checked that the css if referencing the fonts properly. Here is a snippet of the css file.
5. Tested the application on Chrome, Firefox and Opera, same issue

```css
@font-face{font-family:Ionicons;src:url(/fonts/vendor/iview/dist/styles/ionicons.ttf?f3b7f5f07111637b7f12c1a4d499d056) format("truetype"),url(/fonts/vendor/iview/dist/styles/ionicons.woff?39f116d33948df9636a310075244b857) format("woff"),url(/fonts/vendor/iview/dist/styles/ionicons.svg?3f5fdc44d1e78a861fee03f2d8a59c60#Ionicons) format("svg");
```

> What i have in app.js

```js
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * include Vue and Vue Resource. This gives a great starting point for
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the body of the page. From here, you may begin adding components to
 * the application, or feel free to tweak this setup for your needs.
 */

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue';

//  Global event manager, to emit changes/updates
//  such as when user has logged in e.g) auth.js
window.Event = new Vue;

//  Import Element UI Kit
import ElementUI from 'element-ui';
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';
import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/en';

Vue.use(ElementUI, { locale });

//  Import IView UI Kit
import iView from 'iview';
import 'iview/dist/styles/iview.css';

Vue.use(iView);

//  Import Vue Router for custom routes and navigation
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import router from './routes.js';

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  //  Render the main app view
  render: h => h(App),
  //  For our custom routes
  router
});
```

A snippet of what i have in the vue template

```js
<template>
    <el-row :gutter="20">

        <Alert show-icon>An info prompt</Alert>
        <Alert type="success" show-icon>A success prompt</Alert>
        <Alert type="warning" show-icon>A warning prompt</Alert>
        <Alert type="error" show-icon>An error prompt</Alert>
        <Alert show-icon>
            An info prompt
            <template slot="desc">Content of prompt. Content of prompt. Content of prompt. Content of prompt. </template>
        </Alert>
        <Alert type="success" show-icon>
            A success prompt
            <span slot="desc">Content of prompt. Content of prompt. Content of prompt. Content of prompt. </span>
        </Alert>
        <Alert type="warning" show-icon>
            A warning prompt
            <template slot="desc">
            Content of prompt. Content of prompt. Content of prompt.
        </template>
        </Alert>
        <Alert type="error" show-icon>
            An error prompt
            <span slot="desc">
                Custom error description copywriting.
            </span>
        </Alert>
        <Alert show-icon>
            Custom icon
            <Icon type="ios-bulb-outline" slot="icon"></Icon>
            <template slot="desc">Custom icon copywriting. Custom icon copywriting. Custom icon copywriting. </template>
        </Alert>
    </el-row>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

> Page after refresh - Network Tab

[image: The components loaded but font icons did not]

> Page after refresh - Console log Tab

[image: Console log]

> Page after refresh - Elements Tab, the css that is pulling the fonts

[image]

> The font folder

[image]

> What i noticed.

The funny thing is that only the Element UI fonts seems to work. I also tried installing font-awesome fonts, and had no success.

**OTHER IMPORTANT NOTES**

1. I'm developing on Virtual Host
2. I'm developing offline using xammp

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It had to do with one of my style sheets. I found this code: `html, *, body { font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif' !important; font-weight: 400; font-size: 12px; text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important; }` The issue was the `"html, *, body": { font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif' !important; }` part. If you notice the font family is applied to everything, i guess it then replaces even my icon references. When i removed that. The icons started showing again.

[image]